# Is it possible to insert figure, caption, graphic from other tex file

Tags: graphics, floats, cross-referencing

I have two `.tex` files. The first `.tex` file includes two figure: Fig.1 and Fig.2. Could I cross reference whole detail of each figure in other tex file, including graphic, caption, figure number...? Thank all

The code of `file1.tex`

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt, sort&compress]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption,subfig} 
\begin{document}
 This is figure 1
\begin{figure} 
  \centering \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image-a}
  \caption{This is caption 1}
  \label{fig:1}
\end{figure}   

\begin{figure} 
  \centering \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image-b}
  \caption{This is caption 2}
  \label{fig:2}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

In the `file2.tex`

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt, sort&compress]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption,subfig}
\usepackage{xcite}
\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\externaldocument{file1}
\begin{document}
Figure \ref{fig:2} is figure in the file1 file. And I want to show it in below
% Figure2
Figure \ref{fig:1} is figure in the file1 file. And I want to show it in below
% Figure1
\end{document}
```

Comment: Well, you're using `xr-hyper` already

Comment: Is it possible to show image a and b in file2.tex without any \includegraphics again?

Comment: Short answer: Not without much ado. `\includegraphics` is definitely easier

Comment: Means it is impossible? Because the first file looks the paper, and second file look revised one. I just want to show some figure in the paper

Comment: You could use a separate file for your figure, say `myfigure.tex`, put the inclusion into that one and `\input{myfigure}` then for **both** of your regular document files

Comment: You could put your figure environment into a separate .tex file and simply insert them in each file by using `\input{filename.tex}` - Christian was faster

Comment: Sorry, I already have figure in file1.tex (as my paper). In the revised one, I just want to show it, Your solution looks making three file

Comment: TeX (or LaTeX) does not write information about the graphics file itself -- just the label is stored if a caption is used,but nothing more

Comment: @user8430: Sigh -- I'll try a solution, but it's code golfing, most likely ;-)

Comment: Thanks. Because all figure and caption are embedded in the first file (file1.tex). Hence, it take long time to seperate to other file. I hope you can give me one solution for that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update!!!

### Warning -- massive code golfing ahead

I've redefined the `figure` environment a little bit, catching the content of the figure and the caption as well as the stored label. This will save a file per figure environment (not per caption!) named `\jobname.figurenumber.fig` and will store a label named `figlabel:foo` where `foo` is the label given to the caption.

In the second file use `\figextref{foo}` then to load the stored content back.

The previous version used the wrong figure number -- this is fixed now. The problem with multiply defined labels were due to the wrong 'namespace' -- the `storefig` package allows to specify a driver prefix for the references. This must be handled to `\externaldocument` as an option, the the example `reffile` for this. If this storefig option `driverprefix` is omitted, the default prefix `driver` is used.

A bottleneck is the dependance on `hyperref`'s version of `\label` and `\newlabel`.

... and of course it won't work for `figureless` figures, i.e. for `\captionof{...}` stuff.

**driver.tex**

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt, sort&compress]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subfig} 
\usepackage[driverprefix=mydriver]{storefig}

\begin{document}
This is figure 1
\begin{figure} 
  \centering \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image-a}
  \caption{This is caption 1}
  \label{fig:1}
\end{figure}   

\begin{figure} 
  \centering \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image-b}
  \caption{This is caption 2}
  \label{fig:2}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

**reffile.tex** -- the file which uses the stored figure

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt, sort&compress]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption,subfig}
\usepackage{xcite}
\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage[driverprefix=mydriver]{storefig}

\externaldocument[\storefigdriverprefix]{driver}
\begin{document}
Figure \ref{fig:2} is figure in the file1 file. And I what to show it in below

% Now fetch the stuff
\figextref[h]{fig:2}% is figure in the file1 file. And I what to show it in below

\end{document}
```

Here's the changed `storefig` package file -- it allows for correct usage of external references and fetches the figure number from the external file:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}

\ProvidesPackage{storefig}
\RequirePackage{xkeyval}
\RequirePackage{xparse}
\RequirePackage{refcount}
\RequirePackage{letltxmacro}
\RequirePackage{tcolorbox}
\RequirePackage{hyperref}

\DeclareOptionX{driverprefix}[driver]{%
  \gdef\storefig@@driverprefix{#1}%
}

\ExecuteOptionsX{driverprefix=driver}
\ProcessOptionsX

\newcommand{\storefigdriverprefix}{%
  \storefig@@driverprefix%
}


\AtBeginDocument{% 
  \typeout{Package storefig info: Prefix is \storefig@@driverprefix}%
  \def\label#1{%
    \@bsphack
    \begingroup
    \def\label@name{#1}%
    \xdef\@lastlabel{#1}% My hack!
    \label@hook
    \protected@write\@auxout{}{%
      \string\newlabel{#1}{%
        {\@currentlabel}%
        {\thepage}%
        {\@currentlabelname}%
        {\@currentHref}{}%
      }%
    }%
    \endgroup
    \@esphack
  }%
}

\LetLtxMacro\latex@@figure\figure
\let\latex@@endfigure\endfigure


\AtBeginDocument{%
  \RenewDocumentEnvironment{figure}{O{ht}}{%
    \latex@@figure[#1]
    \begingroup
    \tcbverbatimwrite{\jobname.\the\numexpr\value{figure}+1.fig}%
  }{\endtcbverbatimwrite\endgroup%
    % Now load it again
    \input{\jobname.\the\numexpr\value{figure}+1.fig}
    \latex@@endfigure%
    % Store a general label to the .aux file
    \immediate\write\@auxout{%
      \string\newlabel{figlabel:\storefig@@driverprefix:\@lastlabel}{{\jobname.\number\value{figure}.fig}{}{}{}{}}%
    }%
  }
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\figextref}{O{tpb}mo}{%
  \begingroup
  \IfValueTF{#3}{%
    \def\local@driverprefix{#3}%
  }{%
    \def\local@driverprefix{\storefig@@driverprefix}%
  }%
  \latex@@figure[#1]
  \renewcommand{\thefigure}{\getrefnumber{\local@driverprefix#2}}% Redefine the figure counter output according to the value delivered by \
  \InputIfFileExists{\getrefnumber{\local@driverprefix figlabel:\storefig@@driverprefix:#2}}{%
    \typeout{Loading file \local@driverprefix figlabel:\storefig@@driverprefix:#2}%
  }{%
    \typeout{Sorry, not found}%
  }
  \latex@@endfigure
  \endgroup
}


\endinput
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. It works, except figure number. I will wait your improvement

Comment: @user8430: Sorry, I was asleep ;-) See the update ;-)

Comment: Great solution. But I agree on your comments above, would be much easier with separately saved figure code.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner: Thanks -- that's why I said it's code golfing :D

Comment: Really good code. However, I tried to put a tree (using tikzpicture), it has error. Could you consider that case?

Comment: @user8430: No, that was **not** in your question! You can't add one requirement after another one

Comment: @user8430: Again: Your question had no `tikzpicture` -- this is changing the question

Comment: @user8430: I've added a `tikzpicture` environment with some easy drawing and there's no issue about this. It works

Comment: @user8430: Oh my ;-)

Comment: @user8430: Let us clean up the unnecessary comments ;-)